# Performance features in Elasticsearch 5 that are not available in Solr 6

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, elasticsearch-5

I am picking one of the 2 search engines above for a project, and so far both of them have shown to be similar in functionalities.

At least for the requirements that I have:

- Proximity Search
- Boolean queries
- query over all fields
- Boolean queries
- Retrieval of original indexed document
- Real time search requirements, as soon as I index a document, it should be available

Besides that I should have around 1 single type of document, in about 40 million documents - roughly 2 TB of data

that's basically what I need, my questions would be:

**Does one search engine perform better than the other considering my dataset? Such as offering better indexing rates or Search Rates?**

**Am I loosing anything by going with Solr(considering my requirements)?**

**Solr is my choice at the moment.**

Answer (score 1):

some thoughts:

1. nobody can tell you about which one would perform best for you unless you benchmark in your realistic conditions
2. for %99 of users, any of the two would work perfectly
3. if you want to go with one of them (for any reason: you like it, your devs want to try it, you like the logo, whatever), then, don't sweat it, both are very capable.

Comment: Hi @Persimmonium - thanks for your thoughts. Would you say Elasticsearch is more DevOps friendly than Solr?